# I need put a variable inside data for request - Very simple question

Tags: python, python-requests

I need put credentials inside data variable. But, i need start this with ', Because if not, 'true' would be considered the call to a variable, but it's not.

As it stands, of course it doesn't call the credentials variable, but I want a way to do that. I've already tested f' and .format, but without success.

How I do?

```
credentials = str(inputtxt.get()) + str(inputtxt2.get())
    
data = '{"name":credentials, "private":true}'
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think you need to use `True` (capital T) instead of `true`. `True` is the boolean for Python. If you use `true` Python will look for a variable called `true` which doesn't exist.

Comment: I tried it, but unfortunately it doesn't work :c

Answer (score 1):

I'm not exactly sure what you're asking but I when making a dict you don't use quotes it's just:

`data = {"name":credentials, "private":true}`

Comment: It's like I said, it doesn't work, because in this case, then "true" is considered a variable, but that's not it!

Answer (score 0):

Here's my solution:

```
data = '{"name":"replace", "private":true}'
    
data = data.replace('replace', credentials)
```